# EventType clr20r3 - fatalerror - .NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.3053 - Unrecoverable system error

Tags: .net, windows, event-log, fatal-error

After running an WPF (.NET 3.5) application on Windows XP machine for more than 12 hours the application crashes with two EventLog error messages.

The first one is **.NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.3053 - Unrecoverable system error.**

and the second **EventType clr20r3, P1 knxclientconsole.exe, P2 1.0.0.0, P3 4e3961fd, P4 windowsbase, P5 3.0.0.0, P6 488f1338, P7 da, P8 1b, P9 fatalerror, P10 NIL.**

My WPF application is an user interface for an external dll module that I have build too.
That external module is an communication module which communicates through the LAN network
using UDP sockets with an external device.

After using ILDASM to find the location where the error is generated I found the line in my code where the error is generated but not close enough.

```
    public bool ON_Seg4
    {
        get
        {
            return _ON_Seg4;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_ON_Seg4 != value)
            {
                _ON_Seg4 = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ON_Seg4"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The exception is raised in a line **PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ON_Seg4"));**

You can see that the exception is raised in the setter of property  ON_Seg4.

Using ILDASM using the P8 parameter (the IL offset) I found that the exception is raised from the offset 1b :

//000151:                     if (PropertyChanged != null)
  IL_0016:  /* 02   |                  */ ldarg.0

**IL_0017:  /* 7B   | (04)00007C       */ ldfld      class [System/*23000002*
/]System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler/*01000013*/ KNXClientConsole.Controls.Displays.SevenSegment/*02000010*/::PropertyChanged /* 0400007C */**

IL_001c:  /* 14   |                  */ ldnull

IL_001d:  /* FE01 |                  */ ceq

IL_001f:  /* 0A   |                  */ stloc.0

IL_0020:  /* 06   |                  */ ldloc.0

IL_0021:  /* 2D   | 19               */ brtrue.s   IL_003c

If you look this line you can see that there is no detailed code location with offset 1b.
The 1b offset is the last byte of the PropertyChanged handler.
I can't find the OFFSET 1b. Where is it or better what is the cause of the problem ?

**IL_0017:  /* 7B   | (04)00007C       */ ldfld      class [System/*23000002*
/]System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler/*01000013*/ KNXClientConsole.Controls.Displays.SevenSegment/*02000010*/::PropertyChanged /* 0400007C */**

The error is **fatalerror** so I don't have enough explanation for that.

The funny part of the story is that I have 7 similar properties (ON_Seg0 ... ON_Seg6)  with the same code and the exception never happens there only in ON_Seg4.

These properties I use to simulate the ON/OFF state of an 7 segment indicator. These properties are bound to XAML grafic object.

XAML part:

This is the complete story, so if someone has some kind of a solution or hint please help me.